# How to find a code behind a view in hierarchyviewer

Tags: android, android-layout, hierarchyviewer

Android hierarchyviewer shows a ID for each view in the tree view.
The ID is a @ sign followed by a number, e.g @4051d698

In [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html) the purpose of this number is explained as "pointer to view object".

Assuming one has the sources of a very big android project like AOSP.
How can one figure out what is the java source code behind the view by using this ID?

Is there a method I can invoke that tells me what is the R.java entry that is bound to this pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can one figure out what is the java source code behind the view by using this ID?

You can't, at least without a debugger. If you are used to C/C++ development, that hexadecimal value is roughly analogous to a pointer. Just because you have a pointer to a hunk of RAM in C/C++ does not mean that you can determine the source code behind the object resident at that pointer.

Now, it is possible that there is a way in a debugger to supply this hex value and the debugger will match that up to an object and source code. I am not an Eclipse expert, or an expert on another other IDE debuggers, to know whether or not there is a means to do this. However, even if can do this, it will probably only give you the source of the class of the object (e.g., if the `View` is a `ListView`, it might send you to the `ListView` source code), not the source code of what *created* the object.

> Is there a method I can invoke that tells me what is the R.java entry that is bound to this pointer?

First, `R.java` is not "bound" to any pointers.

Second, the `View` in question may not have come from an inflated layout. It might have been created directly in Java code instead.

If the `View` has an "View object ID" (e.g., `id/content`), that can better help you find where it came from, as that will be an `android:id` value, possibly from your layout resources.

Comment: So why hierarchyviewer shows it in the view tree? is there another information i can get from this pointer? according to your explanation it's so minor that a developer shouldn't care from it.

Comment: @ApriOri: "So why hierarchyviewer shows it in the view tree? is there another information i can get from this pointer?" -- if, from your debugger, you see a widget with a certain object ID ("pointer"), you might be able to find it in the Hierarchy View. Otherwise, I have no idea what you would use it for.